# Safari: When I click "Save as" filename does not appear

Tags: php, safari

The user of my website can download files.

Example:

```
<a href="download.php?path=files/videos/myvideo.avi">My Video</a>
```

My problem: In Safari, when the user clicks "Save as", the suggested filename is not "myvideo.avi", but "download.php". This problem does NOT occur in Chrome for example.

PHP code for download (download.php):

```
$path = $_GET['path'];
$doctype = end(explode('.', $path));
$dateiname = end(explode('/', $path));
header("Content-type: application/" . $doctype);
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $dateiname . "\"");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($path));
$fp = fopen($path, 'rb');
fpassthru($fp);
```

How do I achieve that in Safari "myvideo.avi" is suggested as filename when clicking "Save as"?

Answer (score 0):

The issue likely lies with the fact that as written, the script in 'download.php' has not had a chance to fire when the page loads. I think you need to execute some actual PHP code on your page to get the correct link.

```
<a href="<?php **CODE THAT RETURNS CORRECT PATH** ?>">My Video</a>
```

or alternately

```
<?php **CODE THAT GENERATES STRING OF CORRECT PATH**

echo "<a href='".$filepath."'>My Video</a>";

?>
```

This will guarantee that the .php script will run regardless of what browser is being used.